# MOD REWRITE - NOT WORKING

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have a site in which I would like to rewrite / to something like /date/17-10-2014/2 . I thought something like this would work, but this rewrite dont work

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^date/(.*)/(.*)$ date.php?$1&page=$2 [L]
```

But it doesn't work. Hope somebody can help.

Comment: What is not working? Can you provide some details?

Comment: the url is not recognized, giving me an error page...

Comment: What error are you getting and where is this .htaccess located?

Comment: the htaccess file is located in the index folder. im getting a not found error. strange if i only use:   RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^date/(.*)$ date.php?$1 [L]   it is working ... but then i only have this: /date/17-10-2014

Comment: What is the exact URL that gives you 404?

Comment: http://example.com/date/17-10-2014/1 change the page number at the end and it is always the same it wont be recognized

Comment: @user3477680 so you have both sets of rules (one for page number and one without)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your root .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^date/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ date.php?$1&page=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs before `mod_rewrite` and and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.